# How to select only unique entries from a join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to make my block of code more efficient. I have two models and a join table for them. They both have a `has_many :through` relationship. Some parts belong to multiple groups, some only belong to one. I need to get the records that belong to ***only*** one group and in the most efficient manner as there are thousands of parts. Here are my models:

**part.rb**

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible     :name,
                      :group_ids

  has_many            :part_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many            :groups, through: :part_groups, select: 'groups.*, part_groups.*'
end
```

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible     :name,
                      :part_ids

  has_many            :part_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many            :parts, through: :part_groups, select: 'parts.*, part_groups.*'
end
```

**part_group.rb**

```
class PartGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :part_id,
                  :group_id 


  belongs_to      :part
  belongs_to      :group
end
```

What I would like to be able to do is get all the parts that belong only to `Group A` and only to `Group B`, but not ones that belong to both A & B. After struggling with this for hours and getting nowhere I'm using this as a stop gap:

```
@groupA = []
@groupB = []
Part.all.each do |part|
  if part.group_ids.length == 1 
    if part.group_ids.first == 1
      @groupA.push(part)
    elsif part.group_ids.first == 2
      @groupB.push(part)
    end
  end
end
```

This obviously isn't scalable as there will be many groups. I've tried various methods of `join` and `include` that I've been googling but so far nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to rails , So as far i understand this is the structure of your tables.

**parts**

`Id | Name`

groups

`Id | Name`

**part_groups**

`Id | part_id | group_id`

So you can do the following,

`Group.find(1).parts // Parts belong to group A`
`Group.find(2).parts // Parts belong to group B`

so this may give parts that belong to other groups also.
Objective is to get parts that belongs only to group A and only to group B

Try for

`Group.find(1).parts.collect{|row| row if row.groups.count==1}.flatten`

I think this is better approach than yours , because am traversing only those parts which belong to group1.

Comment: That is the setup, however each of those will return instances of parts that are in both groups. For instance say I have 2 parts that are in `group A`, 3 parts in `group B`, but `part 1` and `part 4` are in `group A` and `group B`. `Group.find(1).parts` will return `[part 1, part 2, part 4]` I want to only return `part 2` as it is **ONLY** in `group A`

Comment: For small data sets this should work fine, however, with a larger data set it's going to be generating a lot of DB requests which will seriously lag the application. Which is why I was looking for a SQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

The raw sql for this could look like

```
select parts.* from parts
inner join part_groups on parts.id = part_groups.part_id
left outer join part_groups as group_b on group_b.part_id = parts.id and group_b.group_id = 456
where group_b.id is null and part_groups.group_id = 123
```

Assuming that group a had id 123 and group b had id 456.

What this does is try to join the part_groups table twice (so an alias needs to be used the second time), once where group_id matches group A and once against group B. The use of the left join allows us to require that the second join (against B) produces no rows.

Activerecord doesn't provide much assistance for this, other than allowing you to pass arbitrary sql fragments to `joins`, so you end up with something like

```
Part.select("parts.*").
      .joins(:part_groups).
      .joins("left outer join part_groups as group_b on group_b.group_id = #{groupb.id} and group_b.part_id = parts.id").
       .where(:part_groups => {:group_id => groupa.id}).where("group_b.id is null")
```

Arel (which underpins the query generation part of active record) can generate this sort of query but this isn't exposed directly.